# Is it necessary to protect Rails update actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

If protecting the edit action in a Rails controller so that, for example, only a logged-in user can edit his or her own profile, and no one else's, is it also necessary to protect the update method in the same controller, or is it enough to protect the edit method alone?

```
def edit
  if current_user != User.find(params[:id])
    sound_loud_alarm
  elsif current_user = User.find(params[:id])
    allow_user_to_edit
  else
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how your routing/urls are. If you expose the user-id in the url, you definitely should because once logged on, it would be easy for me to try to reset someones else's password for instance. It is easy for a hacker to show their own form and then do `inspect` and edit the form before posting it.

If you a use url like `GET :profile` and `POST/PUT :profile` which allows a user to only see and edit their own profile, they can no longer try to attempt to edit someone else's profile (since the link between the user/profile-data and the logged in session is made server-side).

If you use UUID url's your urls are already a lot safer (harder to guess someone else url), but that still is no safe-guard so you should verify that the one owner of the session posting the update is the same.

Comment: you could also set this up with a token, right, @nathanvda? Give user a securerandom token, then have the controller or the method reset it for every user every 24 hours or on log out or something?

Comment: Not sure why you want to do that. The user is logged in. You  can just test if the user and posted data refers to the same. A form has the authenticity-token, so rails knows it was posted in the same session. Usually you add a token if a user can no longer login for instance, on password reset. What would the added benefit be of adding a token?

Comment: Your first paragraph above.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Or do you mean the last paragraph (the uuid urls). Using tokens is a lot more work and not sure why you would add superfluous stuff to avoid a single test? Are you logged on and editing your own profile:ok. However if you want to hand someone the right to edit your profile, then you use tokens. Is she logged in and editing her own profile or has a token to edit it. But this is a pretty specific scenario imho

Comment: I suppose. Just wondering. If some evil hacker comes along who know Rails, is there any other way he could try to go round it if you have restricted the edit and update methods?

Comment: Unlike for instance wordpress, there is no generic rails application, so a hacker without access to your code/server has no idea what the server actually does. Rails in general is pretty good in offering good defaults to protect you (authenticity token for instance). Devise is awesome for authentication. A hacker in general has no access to your server, only the webpage/html/data posted itself

Comment: More security tips in general for rails application (maybe you have already seen this, but I thought you might find it useful) : https://github.com/brunofacca/zen-rails-security-checklist

Comment: Thank  you very much.